# Hiding software keyboard in Compose broke Kotlin Flow/Channel events collection

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to hide the soft keyboard in an Android app with Compose UI.
There are events emitted by ViewModel through the kotlin coroutines channel:

```
private val _screenEvents = Channel<ScreenEvent>(capacity = Channel.UNLIMITED)
val screenEvents: Flow<ScreenEvent> = _screenEvents.receiveAsFlow()
```

Events are send like this:

```
_screenEvents.trySend(event)
```

In Compose screen, events are collected in LaunchedEffect and any way to hide keyboard only works once, consecutive events are not collected.

```
val keyboard = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
val inputService = LocalTextInputService.current
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewModel.screenEvents
        .collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is ScreenEvent.CollapseSearchResults -> {
                    // keyboard?.hide()
                    // inputService?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                    bottomSheetState.collapse()
                }
                ...
            }
        }
}
TextField(value = "") {}
```

But if I swap the lines like this:

```
bottomSheetState.collapse()
// keyboard?.hide()
// inputService?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
focusManager.clearFocus()
```

Everything works fine as many times as necessary. But the animations of collapsing bottom sheet and hiding keyboard are sequential and it doesn't suit me.

Can someone explain to me what is the problem and how can I solve it?

#### Edit

This issue is produced if TextField in UI has focus and soft keyboard is shown. The same if user holds BottomSheet while it's animation. It's turned out that BottomSheet animation is cancellable and it throws CancellationException in this cases.

Minimal, complete, reproducible example: https://gist.github.com/Alektas/e86e75a596cb20797f5c9acac238e24f

Comment: Usually flow collection stops if there's an error thrown, so I'd start with trying to catch it. If this doesn't help please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [here](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/c51202654f10a102ef954ccc55c43fdc) is mine, and I'm getting the second value as expected.

Comment: `bottomSheetState.collapse` seems to work in the `LaunchedEffect scope`, Have you tried using `composition scope`?

Comment: @EthanChoi I can't, Lint forbid using Flow operators in a composition scope

Answer (score 1):

Currently, FlowCollector - `bottomSheetState.collapse` is launch in `LaunchedEffect` scope. thus, when an exception occurs in collapse flow collector, `LaunchedEffect` scope is deactivated.

#### Try `Composition CoroutineScope` as below.

```kotlin
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    viewModel.screenEvents
        .collect { event ->
            when (event) {
                is ScreenEvent.CollapseSearchResults -> {
                    // keyboard?.hide()
                    // inputService?.hideSoftwareKeyboard()
                    focusManager.clearFocus()
                    scope.launch { bottomSheetState.collapse() }
                }
                ...
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's turned out that `BottomSheet` animations are cancellable and throw `CancellationException` when `FocusManager` clears focus from `TextField`

[image]

As a workaround, I've wrapped collapsing with `try/catch` for now. I'd be glad If someone showed a better idea how to solve this problem.

```
focusManager.clearFocus()
try {
    bottomSheetState.collapse()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

Comment: is that mentioned in the documentation please share the reference over here so, it will get the authenticity? talking about the first part of the answer

Comment: Shouldn't focusManager.clearFocus() be INSIDE try-catch to actually demonstrate the behaviour?

BTW the solution is to run collapse/expand in local composition scope, not in LauchedEffect() scope.

Answer (score 0):

it's more about re-composition it seems, whenever your state change compose function starts recomposing, `LaunchEffect` `coroutineContext` will be canceled and your bottom sheet show/hide will get interrupted.
to fix this you can try **NonCancelable Job** like following

```
           try {
                    sheetState.show()
                }finally {
                    withContext(NonCancellable){
                        sheetState.show()
                    }
                }
```

here is the reference link [Run non-cancellable block](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#run-non-cancellable-block)